# How can I aggregate data from multiple rows into a single one spread across multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, common-table-expression, denormalization, row-number

I have this table in my database and I want to aggregate data from multiple rows into a single one spread across multiple columns:

```
ID     PID        date              time
1      12         10/04/2014        7:00
2      12         10/04/2014        10:00
3      12         10/04/2014        15:00
4      13         10/04/2014        7:00
5      13         10/04/2014        15:00
6      12         11/04/2014        7:20
7      12         11/04/2014        15:10
8      13         11/04/2014        7:10
9      13         11/04/2014        7:50
10     13         11/04/2014        15:00
11     13         11/04/2014        15:50
```

PID is the employee ID, to be specific it's an attendance system. 
I need to extract this format and insert this form in another table:

```
ID      PID      date               time1          time2         time3       time4
1       12       10/04/2014         7:00           10:00         15:00
2       13       10/04/2014         7:00           15:00
3       12       11/04/2014         7:20           15:10
4       13       11/04/2014         7:10           7:50          15:00       15:50
```

Comment: it's not good idea to store such data in columns... First table looks to be better solution

Comment: What happens if an employee has hundreds of times registered for a day? Or at least some huge amount? You are denormalising the table in a very awkward fashion that doesn't adjust easily.

Comment: i will do it just every month , and at the end of everymonth i can delete it , and i can do it per day its no that problem . i just need the solution for this small problem and i can do it on larger solution

Answer (score 0):

While the concerns stated in the comments are valid, I'll assume that you have a good reason for your specific requirement.

This solution will work with MSSQL:

[SQL Fiddle, MSSQL 2008+](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4b9bb/1/0)

This solution will work with MySQL:

[SQL Fiddle, MySQL 5.5.32](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50049/1/0)

Comment: Jim V am impressed i dont know how you got this solution and i just<br/> want to know how you have didnt , is it an automated <br/>solution by a program or you have made it up . and what is <br/>mssql in brief and what is sql fiddle , and how i can implement the code , iam not used to this kind of queries , in normal i do it like <br/><br/>

$sql="Select / insert ..." <br/><br/>

$result=mysql_query($sql,$connection)<br/><br/>

for($counter=0;$row=mysql_fetch_row($result);$counter){<br/>
   ...<br/>
}<br/><br/>

in this case how can i do it , it would be great if you inform me<br/>

Comment: mr Jim V. does that mean i need to install sql server and create the table on sql server and create the query on it , and work php with sql server ?

Comment: i use mysql front i believe that alot of things doesnt work on it , do i need to work with sql server

Comment: @moussa no, you don't need to work with MSSQL, but this query (although very nice) won't work in mysql.

Comment: then how can i use this query on what platform , am using mysql front , wouldnt it work ? and what can i do ?

Comment: @moussahoussein I added a MySQL version of the solution using a stored procedure.